# Can Apache Wink be used for Android?

Tags: android, rest, apache-wink

I am working with REST services in Android. Is it possible to use [Apache Wink](http://incubator.apache.org/wink/) for implementing REST in Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the client module is Java based you can just link the library into your project and use it.

Comment: Yes my client module is Java based. Thankyou so much

Comment: Can you tel me how to link apache wink to my project

Comment: project properties -> java build path -> libraries